# PAB connection to public testnet or mainnet (Example/Tutorial)

Tags: plutus, testnet, pab, plutus-pab, mainnet

Does anyone know and want to share any information on how to connect PAB to public testnet (not simulator) or mainnet? Are there any examples/tutorials for it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the best instruction here https://gist.github.com/mikekeke/883d56c38e0237444ac98ae5257e174f

Also after the setup on the above link, you can use this starter project generated from the Plutus starter template just updated to work with PAB on testnet https://github.com/invictusappscom/plutus-starter-pab-testnet Here main differences from https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-starter are that dependencies are updated and it is added `plutus-pab.yaml` configuration file. Also here instead of simulator it is using the real PAB https://github.com/invictusappscom/plutus-starter-pab-testnet/blob/main/pab/Main.hs

Another useful resources:

- https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-apps/blob/main/plutus-pab/ARCHITECTURE.adoc
- https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-apps/tree/main/plutus-pab/test-node

Comment: Do I have to run a full node to run the PAB in the testnet?

Comment: Yes, you need to have a running testnet node. Also, wallet server and chain-index connected to the node.